# How to use and access instances of multiple canvases for all methods in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs, jsfiddle

I search for whole month for this problem but it is really difficult for me to solve this issue.Here are the similar answers for this problem but none of them are applicable to my situation:

[Multiple canvases (pages) in Fabric.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276861/multiple-canvases-pages-in-fabric-js)

[How to manage memory in case of multiple fabric js canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030174/how-to-manage-memory-in-case-of-multiple-fabric-js-canvas)

The problem arises when i start to add text and shapes to canvas which gave me an error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined**

Error Starts here:

```
// add text on click
$('#add_text').on("click",function(event){
   var Text = new fabric.Textbox('Sample');
   canvasInstances[0].add(Text).renderAll();
});
// add circle on click
$('#add_circle').on("click",function(event){
   var Circle = new fabric.Circle();
   canvasInstances[0].add(Circle).renderAll();
});
```

[Here is my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PSkmD/153/)

Please Help!!!

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create fabric canvas instance after you creating canvas element, then push to your canvasInstances array.

***DEMO***

```js
// store multiple instances in  the array
var canvasInstances = [];
// add canvas on click
$('.add_canvas').on("click", function(event) {
  var content = document.getElementById("content");
  var newcanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  content.appendChild(newcanvas);
  var fabricCanvasObj = new fabric.Canvas(newcanvas);
  canvasInstances.push(fabricCanvasObj);
});
// add text on click
$('#add_text').on("click", function(event) {
  canvasInstances.forEach(function(canvas) {
    var Text = new fabric.Textbox('Sample');
    canvas.add(Text).renderAll();
  })
});
// add circle on click
$('#add_circle').on("click", function(event) {
  canvasInstances.forEach(function(canvas) {
    var Circle = new fabric.Circle({
      radius: 50,
      left: 10,
      top: 10
    });
    canvas.add(Circle).renderAll();
  })
});
// error starts when adding text and circle in console log.
// what i wanted is to use all methods and access all 
// instances in fabric to make all canvas editable
```

```css
canvas{
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.canvas-container{
    margin: 5px;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button class='add_canvas'>Add Canvas</button>
<button id ='add_text'>Add Text</button>
<button id ='add_circle'>Add Circle</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Durga, thank you for your great and quick answer, can i ask for your suggestion on how to use one canvas for editing when list of, let us say i have canvas list from left is click so that others are not?

Comment: @rhemiel You want to add object on the selected canvas?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, that is really what I wanted to do

Comment: Hi Durga, Here is my sample Interface **[link](https://ibb.co/ckth4J)**

Comment: Is it ok to you if I will create another jsfiddle for this and maybe you can shed some light on how to make this work for me? I will be so happy to do so, thanks

Comment: @rhemiel As I am looping through all canvases, in that use selected canvas to add. You can use canvas `mousedown` event for that.

Comment: thank you again, can you please explain to me further because I'm still confused, sorry

Comment: @rhemiel, have you solved it?